# How to properly write a file with Uri permission?

Tags: android, file, uri

I got access to Android/data (the folder itself, not the app specific one) and now I need to write a file in this folder, but I have no idea how I can do this. I used the following code to check if I could write:

```
String path = "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3AAndroid%2Fdata/document/primary%3AAndroid%2Fdata";

Uri uriPath = Uri.parse(path);
DocumentFile df = DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(activity.getApplicationContext(), uriPath);
System.out.println("1. canWrite? " + df.canWrite());


downloadedFile = new File(df.getUri().getPath(), product + ".zip");
System.out.println(downloadedFile.getAbsolutePath());
System.out.println("2. canWrite? " + downloadedFile.canWrite());
```

This gave me the following output:

```
I/System.out: 1. canWrite? true
I/System.out: /tree/primary:Android/data/document/primary:Android/data/product1.zip
I/System.out: 2. canWrite? false
```

So basically, when using DocumentFile with my application context I can write but when using a File object I can't. How can I overcome this?

Comment: At best, get a document `Uri` pointing to the document you are trying to create. Then use `openOutputStream()` on a  `ContentResolver` to get an `OutputStream` for that document. Write your content to that stream, then flush and close the stream.

Comment: `downloadedFile = new File(df.getUri().getPath(), product + ".zip");` That is nonsense code. You seem to have missed the basics of SAF. In particular creating a file in a folder obtained with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE. An action you never mentioned to begin with.

Comment: @CommonsWare I got an `EISDIR (Is a directory)` error, even the output of `downloadUri.getPath()` shows `/tree/primary:Android/data/document/primary:Android/data/product1.zip`

Comment: @blackapps Yeah man, I'm a beginner with Android in general. But just commenting that this is nonsense code without explaining why doesn't help that much.

Comment: `You seem to have missed the basics of SAF. In particular creating a file in a folder obtained with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE. An action you never mentioned to begin with. ` Well what kind of help do you need more? Google for how to create.... And so on!

Comment: "even the output of downloadUri.getPath() shows" -- well, sure. You are not dealing with files and directories; you are dealing with an abstraction around storage. Only a `Uri` that starts with `file` will have a `getPath()` value that maps directly to some filesystem path. I don't know that you can write anything to the document tree that you think you have access to, particularly at the root of that tree, as you seem to be trying to do.

Comment: @CommonsWare I followed your instructions and got the `EISDIR` error, I did `Uri downloadUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(uriPath, product + ".zip");` and the error occurs when I try to open the output stream using `activity.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(downloadUri)`, I'm missing someting?

Comment: First, as I noted, I do not know that you are allowed to write something in that location. Second, while `Uri.withAppendedPath()` is a fine method, I would not use it here. Use your `df` and [call `createFile()` on it](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentFile#createFile(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) to give you a `DocumentFile` for the document. Call `getUri()` on that `DocumentFile` for the `Uri` to use with `openOutputStream()`.